# Github organization and private repositories

Tags: git, github, versioning

- What would it be a good use of Github organization feature?
- Is it a good idea setting a private repository on github, have various branches, and update the live site project by pulling the data from the master branch of the repository? Other alternatives?

Most of my projects are private, and need to apply version control to all of them, what good practices/tutorials/guides do you know of?

Answer (score 2):

If only you work on that project you don't need a github organization. Just create a single user. If you want it private and not visible for other users buy an account for a few bucks or try bitbucket which offers free private accounts with other limitations.

You again develop locally and share or backup your repo on/to github. From your local branch you push to production. You don't pull from github in production. You can do all that locally from your local repository.

Did you read the ProGit book? It is very useful and might help you getting started with the basic concepts of git. It seems you're missing some important points of a dvcs.

Comment: that's what I am going to do, print the ProGit book tomorrow and start reading. Thanks for sharing the info